# Properties containing references good/bad

Tags: android

I am sort of new in Android/Java (Normally work with PHP and JavaScript). I have read a few articles about memory leaking problems with apps when references are used the wrong way, so I have a question about something I have often seen in other peoples work.

A lot of people, when they need to access things like Views and such in multiple methods, keeps a reference of this in a property which are assigned during the creation of the Activity. From what I have read (or at least understood of what I have read), this is one of the courses for memory leaks?

Is it better to assign an ID to the objects and then search for them in each method? If so, what about dynamic created objects?

Answer (score 2):

Good if you use them correctly, bad if you don't.

You only leak if you pass something outside the activity to another class and the life time of that class is greater than the life time of the activity. Android might destroy your activity once it is no longer the foreground activity and if something outside the activity is holding a reference to it, then the garbage collector cannot release the memory back to the heap.

Be especially careful with activity contexts, statics and singletons.

Simply keeping a reference to a view inside an activity is absolutely normal.

Here's an example of bad (pseudo code);

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{
    public static ImageView activityBackgroundImageView;
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
    myApplication.activityBackgroundImageView= iv; // <==== LEAK

}
```

Actually, the leak is not there, it only leaks when (if) myActivity is finished() or destroyed.

Each object has a reference count - how many objects hold a reference to it.  After you set a reference to the ImageView in your activity, the reference count is one.  You then copy that reference to the Application class.  NB.  Everything in Java is passed by value, so you pass the value of the reference, precisely a copy of the value - i.e. a new reference to the same object.  The reference count on the ImageView is now two.

Sometime later, you finish() your activity and the reference count is decremented.  It is now one.  The garbage collector cannot release that ImageView object since is has a non-zero reference count.

Of course, you could fix it by nulling the reference in the Application but you now have spaghetti code.

Comment: Static references to Images are particularly a problem because they them selves are apparently bound in some way to the activity. So a static reference to a bitmap object will mean the activity is never released.

Comment: Yep, and for anyone who's confused, my original answer used a static bitmap which I later simplified to just referencing the ImageView which will leak the entire activity since it has a reference to the context of the activity which instantiated it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with leaks you're referring to in Android occur when references to things that also hold references to `Context` objects are held by things that are *not* tied to the UI. Holding a reference to a view within its encompassing activity because at some point that activity will no longer be referenced by anything in the system (after `onDestroy()`) and, since there's no longer a reference to it from a garbage collection root (like a global variable), it's eligible for garbage collection. In other words, the circular reference that is set up between an activity and its views no longer matter once no one *else* holds a reference to that activity.

Where the problem comes in is sending in a reference to the activity -- which itself *is* a `Context` -- outside of the UI and activity lifecycle calls. Something like a location listener or something that you forget to deregister. That will hold that reference making the whole tree ineligible for garbage collection. Hence, big leak.

Answer (score 0):

Your observation about the cause of memory leaks isn't quite right.

Storing references to view elements is perfectly fine, its how you do this and use them that can cause memory leaks. For example avoid using static references, for example if you static reference a bitmap image you can inadvertently cause garbage collection issues as Simon pointed out in his answer.

So its fine to do the following.

```
class{
 private TextView myTextView;

onCreate()
 myTextView = findViewById(R.id.mytextview);

myMethod()
 myTextView.text = "hello view."

}
```

The myMethod uses the existing reference purely for convenience, there is nothing stopping you from putting

```
findViewById(R.id.mytextview).text = "hello view";
```

However that would make for really unreadable code if you had a lot of references. So you might use a local scope variable.

```
myMethod()
 TextView myTextView = findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
 myTextView.text = "Hello"
 .....
```

Down to your personal preference, its not going to necessarily cause a memory leak.

Now the issue here is that findViewById is an intensive procedure so you really don't want to be calling that repeatedly. List views are particularly prone to this and will slow down significantly if you don't cater for this.

Therefore in list views you will find people implement a viewHolder pattern. A small object that you assign references to a views child elements to. This object is then assigned to the parent views Tag property. During Subsequent calls to the view you test to see if the views tag property has the viewHolder, if it does it will have a reference to child objects saving you the time and effort of calling findViewById every time you need to update the views contents.

Very rough idea, its implemented slightly differently. 
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.myTextField = findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
    myView.setTag(viewHolder)
    ....
    if (viewHolder)
     viewHolder.text = "hello"

Note that you would only use this in list views. I've not used it as a general rule of thumb.

Look up efficient view holder pattern for list view adapters.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, just wanted to make sure before creating an app that would produce problems for people.

As a safety measure I have added onStop and onRestart to remove and re-create references. This should ensure that nothing of this kind exists while the app is in the background, although I never use references in static properties.